# cronjob not running after machine reboot (requires manual login)

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, cron

I have set up my machines so that I can access them remotely. I also have cronjobs that run on my master server. I often access the machines on my WAN remotely - especially the master server, to make sure everything is running smoothly etc.

On occasion, I have to reboot the machine. However, I notice that whenever I reboot the machine, the cronjobs don't run - unless I physically log into the machine. When I'm at home, this is but a minor inconvenience - however, when I'm half way across the world from the physical machine ...

The cronjobs being run are python scripts and they belong in a folder where only I have access (I suspect this maybe the root of the problem - pun unintended):

```
memyselfandi@yourbox:~/work/skunkworks/scripts$ ls -la
total 64
drwxr-xr-x 9 memyselfandi memyselfandi  4096 Jul 27 07:53 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 memyselfandi memyselfandi  4096 Jul 29 13:51 ..
drwx------ 3 memyselfandi memyselfandi  4096 Feb 18  2016 bash
drwx------ 2 memyselfandi memyselfandi  4096 Apr 23  2015 bat
drwxrwxr-x 8 memyselfandi memyselfandi  4096 Oct 18 16:03 .git
-rw-rw-r-- 1 memyselfandi memyselfandi    27 Jul 27 07:53 .gitignore
drwxr-xr-x 5 memyselfandi memyselfandi  4096 Apr 10  2013 octave
drwxr-xr-x 7 memyselfandi memyselfandi 28672 Aug  6 08:31 python
drwxr-xr-x 3 memyselfandi memyselfandi  4096 Nov 19  2015 R
drwxr-xr-x 2 memyselfandi memyselfandi  4096 Aug  2  2012 testdata
```

typical crontab entry:

```
0 0 28 * * python /home/memyselfandi/work/skunkworks/scripts/python/doyourthang.py >> $(date "+/home/memyselfandi/logs/\%Y\%m\%d.mything.log" )
```

How do I set my master machine up correctly, so that my cronjobs run even after a reboot?

**[[ Useful Info ]]**

- OS: Ubuntu 16.0.4
- bash: GNU bash, version 4.3.46(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: Does it have the same issues when you set up the cronjob as root too?

Comment: @Orphans how would I set up cronjob as root?

Comment: "sudo crontab -e" or login as root with "sudo su" and set up the cronjob. Depending how often you want to run the cronjobs, you can also put the scripts in /etc/cron.daily or /etc/cron.hourly

Comment: @Orphans the machine is currently, scraping realtime data. I will try this out over the weekend and let you know.